# Преобразование данных по средствам JS

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток!

Я получаю вебхук

```
[
  {
    "body": {
    "tg_all_photo_massiv": 
             "{"status": true, 
             "photo": ["https://files.salebot.pro/uploads/message_files/98.jpg", 
                       "https://files.salebot.pro/uploads/message_files/85.jpg"], 
              "kolvo": 2}"
  }
]
```

Далее этот код обрабатывает JS

```
const result = []
 
for (const item of $("Webhook").all()) {
  const photo_arr = JSON.parse(item.json.body.tg_all_photo_massiv)
 
  for (const photo of photo_arr.photo) {
    result.push({
      json: {
        url: photo
      }
    })
  }
}
 
return result;
```

В результате получается то что мне надо!

```
[
  {
     "url": "https://files.salebot.pro/uploads/message_files/98.jpg"
  },
  
  {
     "url": "https://files.salebot.pro/uploads/message_files/85.jpg"
  }
]
```

ВОПРОС! Получая вебхук который указан ниже.. Как мне правильно написать код чтобы преобразовать в  нужный результат

```
[
 {

    "body": {   
    "g_sheet_id": "1pWeLnCCjo42G50IUAdvhSTwFdVoaw055nIENDENFtAY",
    "delete_button": "[2, 6]"
    }
 }
]
```

Нужный результат

```
[
  {
     "row": "2"
  },
  
  {
     "row": "6"
  }
]
```

Я попытался сделать по аналогии... Но я явно сделал что-то не то(( плз.. подскажите как правильно

```
const result = []
 
for (const item of $("Webhook").all()) {
  const rows_arr = JSON.parse(item.json.body)
 
  for (const rows of rows_arr.delete_button) {
    result.push({
      json: {
        row: rows
      }
    })
  }
}
 
return result;
```

Comment: У вас точно приходят такие значения **"delete_button": "[2, 6]"** т.е. delete_button это строка?

Comment: @SwaD Я могу отправить вебхук как строка так и "delete_button": [2, 6] вот так

Answer (score 0):

Если в массиве объектов, в ключе delete_button будет приходить массив, то это можно реализовать следующим образом:

```js
const data = [
 {
    "body": {   
    "g_sheet_id": "1pWeLnCCjo42G50IUAdvhSTwFdVoaw055nIENDENFtAY",
    "delete_button": [2, 6]
    }
 },
  {
    "body": {   
    "g_sheet_id": "1pWeLnCCjo42G50IUAdvhSTwFdVoaw055nIENDENFtAY",
    "delete_button": [3, 8]
    }
 },
  {
    "body": {   
    "g_sheet_id": "1pWeLnCCjo42G50IUAdvhSTwFdVoaw055nIENDENFtAY",
    "delete_button": [12, 16]
    }
 }
];

const res = [];
data.forEach(items => {
  const del = items.body.delete_button;
  del.forEach(item => res.push({ row: item }))
})

console.log(res);
```

Если будет приходить строка, то потребуется некая промежуточная функция преобразования строки к массиву или замена второго цикла forEach на что то иное.